# Convert and merge two string as a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Assume we have two below strings:

```sql
DECLARE @AllowedCardBoardIds NVARCHAR(MAX) = '1,2,3,4,5,6'
DECLARE @AllowedCardBoardIdsAccessTypes NVARCHAR(MAX) = '11,22,33,44,55,66'
```

Also, assume we have a function to split a string as a table.
It returns a sequence values

```sql
Select * FROM dbo.SplitString(',', @AllowedCardBoardIds)
-- result:
Value
------
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Now I want to convert two string to table and merge them as follows:

```
Id     | AccessType
--------------------
1      | 11
2      | 22
3      | 33
4      | 44
5      | 55
6      | 66
```

How should I do it?

I wrote a query as follows:

```sql
DECLARE  @AllowedCardBoardsTable TABLE(
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    AccessType INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @AllowedCardBoardsTable
(
    Id, AccessType
)
SELECT id.[Value], accessType.[Value]
FROM dbo.SplitString(',', @AllowedCardBoardIds) AS id
```

But I don't know how to fill `AccessType` column !

Comment: Have you tried joining the 2 string splits?

Comment: Obligatory note: SQL Server 2008 is completely unsupported for almost 3 years; it is long past time you sorted your upgrade path.

Comment: @DaleK How to Join them, no column to match

Comment: 2008 R2, which you have now tagged instead, is also completely unsupported.

Comment: You're going to have to use a [different technique](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/03/sql-server-2016/string-split) for splitting your strings since `string_split` doesn't guarantee an order.

Comment: You would join them on the same key order - if your current `dbo.SplitString` function does not return a sequence you'll need one that does - but I would not propose one that was compatible for SQL 2008, it's too old and untestable.

Comment: @DaleK I have a function to split string `dbo.SplitString`, I don't know how to merge them

Comment: Is it just chance the sample data is joined both on ordinal position and numerical order? If they can be joined by numerical order you can artificially create a join key with row_number.

Comment: `dbo.SplitString` returns a sequence values

Comment: So join on the sequence value.

Comment: enhance the splzfunction with a Row_number and join both results with that row_number, as you have asplit function, that we don't know about, you must help yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @AllowedCardBoardsTable TABLE(
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    AccessType INT NOT NULL
);

DECLARE @AllowedCardBoardIds NVARCHAR(MAX) = '1,2,3,4,5,6';
DECLARE @AllowedCardBoardIdsAccessTypes NVARCHAR(MAX) = '11,22,33,44,55,66';

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT CardBoardIds = CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
          REPLACE(@AllowedCardBoardIds, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
          ']]></r></root>' AS XML)
        , CardBoardIdsAccessTypes = CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
          REPLACE(@AllowedCardBoardIdsAccessTypes, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
          ']]></r></root>' AS XML)
)
, rs2 AS 
(
    SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (t.c))
        , Id = c.value('.', 'INT') 
    FROM rs
    CROSS APPLY CardBoardIds.nodes('/root/r/text()') AS t(c)
)
, rs3 AS 
(
    SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (t.c))
        , Id = c.value('.', 'INT') 
    FROM rs
    CROSS APPLY CardBoardIdsAccessTypes.nodes('/root/r/text()') AS t(c)
)
INSERT INTO @AllowedCardBoardsTable (Id, AccessType)
SELECT rs2.id, rs3.Id 
FROM rs2 INNER JOIN rs3 ON rs3.rn = rs2.rn;

-- test
SELECT * FROM @AllowedCardBoardsTable;
```

**Output**

```
+----+------------+
| Id | AccessType |
+----+------------+
|  1 |         11 |
|  2 |         22 |
|  3 |         33 |
|  4 |         44 |
|  5 |         55 |
|  6 |         66 |
+----+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use one of the built-in string-splitting methods, rather than trying to roll your own.

Unfortunately, current versions of SQL Server do not support `STRING_SPLIT` with an `ordinal` column. But in this case you can hack it with `OPENJSON`

```sql
DECLARE @AllowedCardBoardIds NVARCHAR(MAX) = '1,2,3,4,5,6';
DECLARE @AllowedCardBoardIdsAccessTypes NVARCHAR(MAX) = '11,22,33,44,55,66';

SELECT
  id = acb.value,
  AccessType = at.value
FROM OPENJSON('[' + @AllowedCardBoardIds + ']') acb
JOIN OPENJSON('[' + @AllowedCardBoardIdsAccessTypes + ']') at
  ON at.[key] = acb.[key];
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=11ce0fd099c03cb8bd1a5a9205270975)

I strongly suggest you store your data properly normalized in the first place, such as in a table variable, temp table, or normal table.

Comment: It is SQL Server 2008R2

Comment: Thanks, But it is not work on SQL 2008 R2